# Cross domain from SignalR2 to phantomjs

Tags: javascript, signalr, phantomjs

this project work right on SignalR v1.1.4, client is phantomjs with cors:

```
webpage = require "webpage"
websocket = webpage.create()
serverUrl = "http://www.domain.com"
websocket.injectJs './jquery-2.1.0.min.js'
websocket.injectJs './jquery.signalR-1.1.4.min.js'
websocket.includeJs serverUrl + '/signalr/hubs', ->
    websocket.evaluate (serverUrl)->
        $.support.cors = false
        $.connection.hub.url = serverUrl + '/signalr'
        taskHub = $.connection.taskHub
        $.connection.hub.start().done ->
            taskHub.server.registerAgent "xxx"
            #……
        taskHub.client.castTesk = (task) ->
            #……
    , serverUrl
```

until upgrade SignalR to v2.0.2. 
i remove RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(new HubConfiguration() { EnableCrossDomain = true }) on Application_Start() and add Startup.cs:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SpiderMan.Startup))]
namespace ProjectNamespace {
    public partial class Startup {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
            app.Map("/signalr", map => {
                map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration {
                    EnableJSONP = true
                };
                map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

then $.connection.hub.start() work right always, but taskHub.client.castTesk() could not be triggered, without any error message.

update:
v1.2.1 is work fail also like v2.0.2. 
And, Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR Package with any version on server could not affect this issus. client work right with jquery.signalR-1.1.4.min.js, fail with jquery.signalR-1.2.1.min.js always, for any server signalR version.

Comment: Try enabling client-side logging: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#logging That should give you more diagnostic information which you can add to your question.

Comment: thanks your suggestion. i enabled log, the lastline information is "Invoked taskhub.RegisterAgent", no error no warn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define your castTesk method before you start your connection. This issue is discussed in the "Connection started before subscriptions are added" section of the [SignalR Troubleshooting Guide](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/troubleshooting-and-debugging/troubleshooting).

```
#……
taskHub.client.castTesk = (task) ->
    #……
$.connection.hub.start().done ->
    taskHub.server.registerAgent "xxx"
    #……
```

The problem is that if you call `$.connection.hub.start()` before you define `taskHub.client.castTesk`, SignalR will not subscribe the client to the TaskHub.

You will still be able to invoke server-side methods belonging to the TaskHub such as RegisterAgent, but the server will be unable to invoke client methods such as castTesk.

I would also suggest removing the `$.support.cors = false` line. This will cause SignalR to always use JSONP instead of CORS even if the browser supports CORS.